# Cannot Find Symbol createAccessBeans(java.util.Collection) when Compiling EJB 1.1 IBM Commerce Project

Tags: java, ejb, websphere

I am trying to "Mavenize" our existing Commerce solution. However, I am getting a weird error when I try to run mvn compile I get the following error.

```
[ERROR] /home/user/tmp/IBM/WCDE_ENT70/workspace/WebSphereCommerceServerExtensionsData/ejbModule/org/ecommerce/wcs/changerequest/ChangeRequestAccessBean.java:[347,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method createAccessBeans(java.util.Collection)
[ERROR] location: class org.ecommerce.wcs.changerequest.ChangeRequestAccessBean
```

When I check the class it is related to the com.ibm.ivj.ejb.runtime.AbstractEntityAccessBean class which IBM has neglected to include JavaDoc for anywhere. I look into eclipse and it shows me the method in question was correct using code complete, however, it still fails with maven.

I am wondering if it isn't a customisation to the IBM jre (I am not using that for this POC) and if there is no way around it (short of extending the class and reimplementing).

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem had to do with multiple imports of different versions of the same dependency. Now this has been resolved.